# NetLogo: How to ask a turtle to do something if "at least one member of its network"

Tags: netlogo

I want to ask turtles to do something in two cases: 1) if ALL the members of their network show a particular feature, 2) if AT LEAST one member of their network show a particular feature. For the first case I tried

```
                ask turtles [ if all? link-neighbors [audit?-last-tick = false] [
                set delta 0]
```

and it works. 
For the second case I tried

```
                ask turtles [ if any? link-neighbors [audit?-last-tick = true] [
                set delta 1]
```

or

```
                ask turtles [ if one-of link-neighbors [audit?-last-tick = true] [
                set delta 1]
```

but it does not work.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `with`:

```
ask turtles [
  if any? link-neighbors with [ audit?-last-tick ] [
    set delta 1
  ]
]
```

Note that you can also use `with` instead of `if`:

```
ask turtles with [ any? link-neighbors with [ audit?-last-tick ] ] [
  set delta 1
]
```

And that, unless you expect `audit?-last-tick` to possibly have a non-boolean value, you can directly write `[ audit?-last-tick ]` instead of `[ audit?-last-tick = true ]`.